# Multi-Channel Funnels response per day not total

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client, google-reporting-api

I'm doing this request in Python / Postman:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/mcf?
ids=ga:xxxx&metrics=
mcf:assistedConversions&
dimensions=&
start-date=2011-10-01&
end-date=2011-10-31
```

But I only seem to be able to get the total number of results.

1/ Can I get it on a daily granularity? I know that GA API has the ga:date optional parameter, but this does not work in combination with the MCF API and I couldn't find anything similar for MCF.

Do I have to iterate through each day to get the results at a daily granularity?

2/ Is the 30 days lookback applied to API calls? If just put the end date 4 years ahead, will it give me the full results?

Answer (score 1):

**Daily granularity**: You should add the [`mcf:nthDay` dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/dimsmets/time#mcf:nthDay) to break the results down into individual days within the specified range:

> Index for each day in the specified date range. Index for the first
> day (i.e., start-date) in the date range is 0, 1 for the second day,
> and so on.

**Loopback time**: yes it's [30 days and can'be be changed](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/mcfDevGuide#intro):

> Note: The Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API uses a non-adjustable
> 30-day lookback window.

*If just put the end date 4 years ahead, will it give me the full results?*

Why don't you test to find out and let us know :) ?